# How to make the JAVA interface being "implements" by other class after exporting as JAR?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I’m building an App using Java/Eclipse, and my app contains a custom Event and Listener, which means I have defined the interface, Event, Event source(the class who triggers the Event), Event Handler(the class who “implements” the interface and handles the Event) in my Android project. It works fine in my own app.
However, I want to make my source code into a .jar so that other source project can import it. What I’m trying to do is making the project which imports my .jar can see and “implements” my interface, then receive the Event and handles the Event from my .jar with its own method . 
I don’t know how to do this and if there’s any simple sample code or a guide I will be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have default visibility (package) or even protected/private in your HelloListener?
What do you mean it works fine in your own project? When you have the source right in your project and not a JAR?
I guess you have added the jar to your classpath. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: right click your project --> export --> Java --> JAR file

Comment: Thank you for the steps! I've followed it and imported the .jar in other project and try to implement the interface from my .jar, however it says "the type HelloListener(my interface) is not visible". How can I fix this and make my interface been seen? thank you!(I also posted the screenshot of the error message)

Comment: @Alison what's your HelloListener looks like? Is that interface 'public'?